# Javascript file (excanvas) not working when I load it at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, excanvas

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

  <script src="/js/msgv/widgets/excanvas2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function canvasTest(){
      console.log("beginning canvasTest");
      var b_canvas = document.getElementById("regularCanvas");
      var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d");
      b_context.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onLoad="canvasTest()">
    <canvas id="regularCanvas" style="border: 1px dotted; float: left;" class="clear" height="225" width="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

The only difference between the two is where I'm loading it in the page. Everything works fine when I load excanvas in the head. I get an error when I load it at the bottom of the body.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function canvasTest(){
      console.log("beginning canvasTest");
      var b_canvas = document.getElementById("regularCanvas");
      var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d");
      b_context.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onLoad="canvasTest()">
    <canvas id="regularCanvas" style="border: 1px dotted; float: left;" class="clear" height="225" width="300"></canvas>
  <script src="/js/msgv/widgets/excanvas2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well explained in the [official documentation](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions):

> The excanvas.js file must be included in the page before any occurrences of canvas elements in the markup. This is due to limitations in IE and we need to do our magic before IE sees any instance of  in the markup. It is recommended to put it in the head.