# excanvas js is not working in IE8

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, canvas

getting below error on IE8

```
canvas.getContext("2d") Unexpected call to method or property access.Error
```

i have also add

```
 if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
                G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
            }
```

how to run canvas in IE8 with ecanvas.js. 
also i have [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362847/problem-getting-excanvas-to-use-getcontext-in-ie8) but no luck for me on it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're sure you've included the file in your markup (as per the documentation):

```
<head>
<!--[if IE]><script src="PATH_TO_JS_FILE"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Are you definitely instantiating your "canvas" properly?  If you're doing it dynamically then:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Or if you've added your canvas to the page's markup are you grabbing a reference to it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
```

Your browser doesn't know what to do with your canvas object, so it looks like it's not instantiated properly.

Comment: thanks for reply...yes its problem of grabbing a reference from markup.

Comment: great stuff, glad you fixed your problem!